# Netstat doesn't show a process for port 53, how can I unbind the port and stop listening on it?

Tags: 20.04, dns, port-forwarding, netstat

I am trying to install AdGuardHome but it is unable to bind to 0.0.0.0:53 because it is already being used. I tried their automated fix, as well as manually following their instructions:

```
Deactivate DNSStubListener and update DNS server address. Create a new file: /etc/systemd/resolved.conf.d/adguardhome.conf (create a /etc/systemd/resolved.conf.d directory if necessary):

[Resolve]
DNS=127.0.0.1
DNSStubListener=no
Specifying 127.0.0.1 as DNS server address is necessary because otherwise the nameserver will be 127.0.0.53 which doesn't work without DNSStubListener.

Activate another resolv.conf file:

sudo mv /etc/resolv.conf /etc/resolv.conf.backup
ln -s /run/systemd/resolve/resolv.conf /etc/resolv.conf
Restart DNSStubListener:

systemctl reload-or-restart systemd-resolved
```

I followed another thread that suggested running netstat -pn to get a list of ports and processes, but was unable to find anything with port 53.

I also ran netstat -an | grep 192.168.1.17:53 and got:

```
tcp        0      0 192.168.1.17:53         0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
udp        0      0 192.168.1.17:53         0.0.0.0:*
```

I previously had installed adguard but I uninstalled it. I believe that is why the port is open. Is there a way to unbind it?

Comment: To see process information from netstat, you will need to add the `-p` option and run it with elevated privileges ex. `sudo netstat -apn | grep 192.168.1.17:53`

Comment: One could `sudo lsof -i:53` instead.